# MongoDB : Referencing first query in the second query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am trying execute the following two queries inside Mongodb. I am stuck on how I can properly reference "Query #1" from within "Query #2" . The goal here is to group by a "product_id". "Product_id" is less granular than "variant_id." I can also denormalize and include product_id within the "events_inventories" collection but I am resisting that for now.

Here it be. Any help is greatly appreciated!:

//QUERY #1:

```
var variant_inventory = db.getCollection('events_inventories').aggregate([

{
    $match: {
        "updated_at": {
            "$gt": new Date(2014, 1, 1)
        },
    }
},

{
    $group: {
        _id: {

            variant: "$variant_id",
            date: {
                "yr": {
                    "$year": "$updated_at"
                },
                "mo": {
                    "$month": "$updated_at"
                },
                "day": {
                    "$dayOfMonth": "$updated_at"
                }
            }

        },

        inventory: {
            $min: "$count_on_hand"
        }

    }

}
]);
```

//QUERY #2

```
db.getCollection('products_variants').aggregate([{
    $match: {
        variant_id: "$variant_inventory._id.variant"
    }
},

{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            product_id: "$product_id",
            date: "variant_inventory._id.date",
        },
        prodinventory: {
            $min: "variant_inventory.inventory"
        }
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: Are you aware that the variable `variant_inventory` holds a cursor since [**`aggregate`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method returns a cursor and you will need to use the [**`toArray()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor.toArray) method to get the result in an array? Also, it would be really great if you could edit your question to include some sample documents to test with from both collections and the expected final result from both queries.

Comment: in the second query you want to have match { variant_id: { $in [ <array-of-product_ids> ] } }    so you need to convert the first result to an array of product_ids.  I'll show a small code sample in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn the result of the first query into an array of variant id's and then pass that to the second query using "$in".

Example:

```
query1=db...;
ids=[];
query1.forEach(function(d) { ids.push(d._id.variant); });
query2=db.collection.aggregate( {$match: { variant_id:{$in: ids } } } );
```